# Running rspec on Aptana 3

Tags: ruby, rspec, aptana

I am trying to make the [2 minute tutorial](http://relishapp.com/rspec/file/twominutetutorial) run on Aptana 3.

I've already created both `.rb` files, but I am left wondering what button or command should I run to make my `game_spec.rb` file run.

How to run my rspec tests in Aptana?

Comment: Could anyone help? If it is dead obvious then it's easy to answer and get the points..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is not quite correct.
First, you need to place you game_spec.rb into spec/ folder.

The tutorial assumes to use Terminal so you need to click on "Open Terminal" action on toolbar, then type (or copy/paste)

```
rspec spec/game_spec.rb --color --format doc
```

Alternatively, you could use menu Commands/RSpec/Run Examples (there is a shortcut too for it), but it requires fixing the RSpec Aptana bundle. Follow these steps:

1. open menu Commands/RSpec/Edit the bundle
2. Find and open lib/lib/spec/mate/runner.rb
3. Edit lines 8 and 11 to replace 'spec' with 'rspec'
4. Save the file. Restart Aptana Studio.

Also, I'd define TM_RSPEC_OPTS environment variable and set it to "--format doc"

Chers,
Max

Comment: Is that the only way? I'd like to stay away from having to use the command line, if possible (otherwise I'd just code with a text editor).

Comment: The tutorial specifically assumes Terminal use. See updated version w/o terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana ships with an RSpec bundle (I guess it's called a bundle, but anyways you should have it).

Go to `Commands -> RSpec -> Run Single Example` (or just press `Ctrl + Shift + R`) while having the `game_spec.rb` file selected and it should run only that spec.

Comment: I had noticed that menu in the past. But even selecting game_spec.rb, it seems that all the menu items are greyed out.