# How do I configure Aptana 3 IDE to run rspec tests for my Rails project?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on Mac High Sierra.  I have imported my Rails 5 project and would like to debug some rspec tests in the IDE.  On the command line, I normally run

```
bundle exec rspec /spec/path/test_spec.rb
```

but I would like to be able to set breakpoints and debug at a more granular level.  I tried following the instructions for setting up rspec here -- [Running rspec on Aptana 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894209/running-rspec-on-aptana-3) but when I open my Command menu and select the "rspec" option, most of the menu options are empty

[image]

Even when I further expand the menus, everything is disabled (empty) ...

[image]

What else do I need to do to configure my IDE to run rspec tests?

Comment: Did you tried again after restarting it ?

Comment: Also, try [this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/) tutorial once.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try again after restarting it?

You can try `Ctrl + Shift + R` and also this tutorial specifically assumes Terminal use.
If your errors still remain then try reaching the `mailing list`

[mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rspec)

Comment: I can run the spec fine in a terminal, but the reason I want to use the IDE is so I can do things that a termianl cannot do easily, like debugging.

Comment: Oh, I see, So did any of these things helped you?

Comment: Hi, It's not that I'm getting errors, it's just that I don't know how to configure the IDE and I can't find anything in the documentation to help me along.

Comment: Oh. Now I got it. In that case, I need to run the IDE and experience the situation, Similar to what you are in.